# Declare the slope coefficient in the Linear Regression model as a variable

Tags: r, regression

Creating linear regressions in R are great because they are simple. However, I have found a lot of difficulty in referring back to the slope of the newly created trend line.

I have the following:

```
#Reproducible data
v1<-c(1:20)
v2<-c(1:20)
v2<-v2^2
df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(v1,v2))

v3<-c(1:20)
v4<-c(1:20)
v4<-v4^3
df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(v3,v4))

#Model
lm1<-lm(v2~v1,df1)
lm2<-lm(v4~v3,df2)
```

However how do I declare the slope coefficients of `lm1` and `lm2` as variables for later use? I am unable to find anything about declaring it, but quite a lot of the interpretation, which I understand already what the slope of it is.

A step further: What if I create a linear model with more than 1 explanatory variables. How would I get the slope coefficients and declare them as a variable?

```
#Reproducible data
v1<-c(1:20)
v2<-c(1:20)
v2<-v2^2
v5<-c(0:.01,20)
df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(v1,v2,v5))

v3<-c(1:20)
v4<-c(1:20)
v4<-v4^3
v6<-c(0:.01,20)
df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(v3,v4,v6))

#Model
lm1<-lm(v2~v1+v5,df1)
lm2<-lm(v4~v3+v6,df2)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reproducible example. However I'm not exactly sure what you mean by declaring it as a variable, do you mean something like `slope1 <- coeff(lm1)[2]` ?

Comment: What do you mean by _declare_? If you mean _assign_ to an object/variable. What @kath suggests should be fine `(coef(lm1)[2])`

Comment: @kath sounds like an answer to me. I used `coef` instead of `coeff`

Comment: Oh sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the coefficients from your regression using:

```
 lm1$coefficients
 lm2$coefficients
```